# How to make .py Python files actually execute in the browser?

Tags: python

I have tried searching online like crazy with no avail. PHP is as simple as naming the file .php and writing PHP. I know people say it's that simple for Python, but I have found no useful guides in setting it up. I merely want to practice Python on my computer via WAMP or another alternative. I am on Windows Vista.

I cannot get .py files to execute correctly. The actual text:

```
print("Hello!")
```

Appears just as that rather than `"Hello!"`. I don't know what to do to make it actually work in my browser.

Any help or pointing towards guides would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *“PHP is as simple as naming the file .php and writing PHP”* – Well, actually what happens is that the webserver provides a special file handler for the `.php` extension and runs that through the PHP parser whenever a PHP-file is requested. You can do the same with Python, for example using [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/).

Comment: PHP doesn't execute in the browser. It is executed in the *web server* by the PHP interpreter, usually `mod_php`. Get yourself a Python web server.

Comment: I think what you want is Python CGI since you want to see Python do stuff on the browser. See this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm or google for Python CGI.

Comment: installing python from a binary installer should set this up for you ... otherwise you will probably need to right click and say "always open with..." or whatever on a .py file ...

Comment: See http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming

Comment: IIRC mod_python is deprecated, but you might take a look at mod_wsgi or mod_wsgi_py3

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not execute in the browser. It is executed on the server side then the output is sent by the web server to the browser.

If you want a simple way to use Python to process web requests take a look at web.py ([http://webpy.org](http://webpy.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

Your server should handle Python code. Take a look at framework `Django`. And as for servers I can suggest you `http://webfaction.com`